# how can i add a progressbar to a mp3 player i created in swift using AVPlayer NOT AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift

here is my code of how im playing my mp3 from a live url i just cannot find any updated information for swift to use avplayer not avaudioplayer.. thank you in advance to all comments and helpers

```
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
var player = AVPlayer()

  var error : NSError?
    var sucess : Bool?
    do{
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback,withOptions: .DefaultToSpeaker)
        _ =  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        sucess = true

    } catch let NotSucessError as NSError{error = NotSucessError
        sucess = false}

    if !sucess! {
        NSLog("Fail to set audio session. Error:\(error)")
    }

    let url = NSURL(string: trackURL)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    player.play()
```